# Scala App args can't be val

Tags: scala

I have the following Scala 2.12.x code:

```
object Myapp extends App {
  val bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper()
  val config = bootstrapper.bootstrap(args)
}

class Bootstrapper {
  def bootstrap(val args : Array[String]) : Config = {
    null
  }
}
```

The above causes a compiler error inside my `Bootstrapper` class, complaining about `args` being a `val`:

```
identifier expected but 'val' found.
```

When I change `val args : Array[String]` to just `args : Array[String]` the compiler error goes away. **Why?**

Comment: you example should not compile even if you remove val. because method name "bootstrap" is not a constructor. You need to rename it to "apply"

Comment: Ahhh! Sorry @BogdanVakulenko (+1) it was just a copy and paste error, please see my updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala method parameters are always vals, unlike in Java where you have to explicitly mark them as `final`. That's why marking a method parameter as `val` is not part of the syntax.

Comment: Thanks @Jasper-M (+1), is it possible to mark method parameters as `var`?

Comment: @smeeb It's not possible. It's also not very good practice anyway to assign a new value to a method parameter, and Scala simply doesn't even allow it.

Comment: Even if it was possible to assign them as `var`, it would not have changed anything because Java and Scala are both paas-by-value wrt variables.

Comment: It would change the fact that you can assign a new value to the parameter inside the method, same as in Java... Not that you should want to do that.